# No Files Created When Trying To Migrate JS from TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have a Next.js project in Typescript. I need to get it back to Javascript. I need to remove all Typescript markup or compile it to ES2018 JS.

I tried to run tsc command at the project root with this config:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": { "*": ["types/*"] },
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2018"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "target": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [".next", "server/**/*.*"]
}
```

Nothing happened.

I want .ts files to be replaced with .js files. If not possible, I need .js files next to .ts files. I can manually delete .ts files.

Comment: You have `"noEmit": true` in your config.

Comment: The problem is solved. If you answer the question with answer button, I'll mark it with green tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `"noEmit": true` in your config, which causes the compiler to not emit any `.js` files. As for deleting the `.ts` files you will need to do that manually.